# Coverting jpgs with exif to tiff files

Tags: geolocation, gis, tiff, exif, dji-sdk

I have jpgs from a drone flight with exif data. I need to convert them to tiff files including the geolocation data. These images are all separate, not an orthomosaic. Pix4D does not seem to work, as it seems designed to make an othomosaic with multiple pictures. And I do not have Agisoft Metashape. Global Mapper is able to read the exif data and make a point picture, but when exported as tiff and opened in ArcGIS Pro, I just see the white square with the camera icon, not the picture.

Any ideas of how to make this work? Could be a solution using Global Mapper and solving the issue there of the picture format or in any other software. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.